# Create the Parent-Child-Sibling tree in c++

Tags: visual-c++, tree

I'm a c++ n00b. I'm learning c++ now. I got a problem which asks me to create parent-child-sibling tree and do some basic stuff like creating and destroying nodes and printing siblings of particular nodes. So can you explain me how to create that?

Comment: What did you try? There are a big lot of books and examples online on that issue!! What programming books have you read?

Comment: I've tried in google and understood nothing. can you give me some info assuming I know nothing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29 may give you an idea about what is a tree data structure. Once you understand that, you may begin the implementation.

Comment: The best way is to go into a library (e.g. at your university) and to take several hours to read good books about algorithmics and C++ programming. Don't expect people to do your homework, that won't help you at all (the purpose of a homework is to teach something valuable to you). Really, spend several hours reading good books.

Comment: @user1141641: If we are to assume that reading explanations has not helped you, what are you hoping we will write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to extend a linked list data structure to use parent and child elements. Here's a nice tutorial on linked lists: http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/linkedlist.htm

Once you get the idea, extending the code will be easy.

Comment: the link to the page is broken.